# Getting distance from Google Direction API in Android

Tags: android, distance, google-directions-api

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=-20.291825,57.448668&destination=-20.179724,57.613463&sensor=false&mode=%22DRIVING%22

For example this link generate the following:

```
"routes" : [
      {
         "bounds" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : -20.1765204,
               "lng" : 57.6137001
            },
           "southwest" : {
               "lat" : -20.2921672,
               "lng" : 57.4472155
            }
         },
         "copyrights" : "Map data ©2014 Google",
         "legs" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "24.6 km",
                  "value" : 24628
               },
```

i want to extract only the distance and display it in android

Comment: Have you looked at the API? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Answer (score 9):

To get a distance from a Google Maps you can use Google Directions API and JSON parser to retrieve the distance value.

**Sample Method**

```
private double getDistanceInfo(double lat1, double lng1, String destinationAddress) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            Double dist = 0.0;
            try {

            destinationAddress = destinationAddress.replaceAll(" ","%20");    
            String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + latFrom + "," + lngFrom + "&destination=" + latTo + "," + lngTo + "&mode=driving&sensor=false";

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;
            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


                response = client.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
                int b;
                while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                    stringBuilder.append((char) b);
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {

                jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());

                JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");

                JSONObject routes = array.getJSONObject(0);

                JSONArray legs = routes.getJSONArray("legs");

                JSONObject steps = legs.getJSONObject(0);

                JSONObject distance = steps.getJSONObject("distance");

                Log.i("Distance", distance.toString());
                dist = Double.parseDouble(distance.getString("text").replaceAll("[^\\.0123456789]","") );

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return dist;
        }
```

For details on parameters and more details on what are the different options available, please refer this.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: @Prem I see this as a GET request rather than a POST request.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. You can even get the duration in this way: JSONObject duration= steps.getJSONObject("duration");

Comment: why you are not passing parameter "&key=YOUR_API_KEY" ?

Answer (score 4):

```
public class ApiDirectionsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, StringBuilder> {

    private static final String TAG = makeLogTag(ApiDirectionsAsyncTask.class);

    private static final String DIRECTIONS_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions";
    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

    // API KEY of the project Google Map Api For work
    private static final String API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY";

    @Override
    protected StringBuilder doInBackground(URL... params) {
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground of ApiDirectionsAsyncTask");

        HttpURLConnection mUrlConnection = null;
        StringBuilder mJsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(DIRECTIONS_API_BASE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?origin=" + URLEncoder.encode("Your origin address", "utf8"));
            sb.append("&destination=" + URLEncoder.encode("Your destination address", "utf8"));
            sb.append("&key=" + API_KEY);

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            mUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(mUrlConnection.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1){
                mJsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error processing Distance Matrix API URL");
            return null;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error connecting to Distance Matrix");
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (mUrlConnection != null) {
                mUrlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return mJsonResults;
    }
}
```

I hope that help you!

Answer (score 2):

Just check below link. You will probably get idea of it and try it on your own.

http://about-android.blogspot.in/2010/03/sample-google-map-driving-direction.html

Also you can use Google Distance Matrix API

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

Answer (score 1):

```
String url = getDirectionsUrl(pickupLatLng, dropLatLng);
new GetDisDur().execute(url);
```

Create URL using latlng

```
private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

        String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

        String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;

        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        String mode = "mode=driving";

        String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor + "&" + mode;

        String output = "json";

        return "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;
    }
```

Class **GetDisDur**

```
private class GetDisDur extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            String data = "";

            try {
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                JSONArray routes = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");

                JSONObject routes1 = routes.getJSONObject(0);

                JSONArray legs = routes1.getJSONArray("legs");

                JSONObject legs1 = legs.getJSONObject(0);

                JSONObject distance = legs1.getJSONObject("distance");

                JSONObject duration = legs1.getJSONObject("duration");

                distanceText = distance.getString("text");

                durationText = duration.getString("text");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide code for 'data = downloadUrl(url[0]);'